# Django runserver not running when importing another python file

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django, so I am trying to import a python file in the views.py inside my Django app.

When I run the server with `python manage.py runserver` it's not doing anything. When I comment out the import part it works for some odd reason

I've already tried some solutions. Like:

`import [file]`

`from . import [file]`

`from .[file] import [function in the file]`

and all these still didn't work.

#### DETAILS:

-Python version 3.7.3
                                                                 -Django version 2.2.5

#### CODE:

*Note: this is in `views.py`*

```
import bot

def process(request):
    username = request.POST["username"]
    email = request.POST["email"]
    code = generate_code(random.randrange(5, 12))

    data = {"username": username, "email": email, "code": code}

    bot.say("Hi", channel_id=600617861261819906)

    return render(request, "process.html", data)
```

Comment: Could you please post your error message?

Comment: @hendrikschneider I would but there is literally no error message

Comment: Could you show us your file directory?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/p5kjal Here... (I'm also new to stackoverflow so thats might be a problem I guess)

Answer (score 0):

Given the that you could remove your import and it's working. Maybe, you did not add your view in one of `urls.py` file? like here in Django tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/#write-your-first-view

Assume that your project structure looks something like this.

```
django_project/
    manage.py
    django_project/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    your_app/
        __init__.py
        apps.py
        urls.py
        views.py
```

your `django_project/your_app/urls.py` should look something like this

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('process/', views.process, name='process'),
]
```

and your `django_project/urls.py`

```
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('your-app/', include('your_app.urls')),
]
```

Also, make sure you add your app in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`.

If these are not the case, I think more infos would be useful.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I still haven't done this yet, and I will give you more information about my project if it didn't work. But what exactly do you mean `make sure you add your app in Installed_Apps`? Because I haven't done this yet

Comment: Hi @Philiero, The `INSTALLED_APPS` part I meant is here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial02/#activating-models. But, now that I read the document again, you don't need it for making your views working. It will be useful if you want to connect Django with a database. Sorry, for making confusion.

Comment: It's alright, well I'll tell you more information about the project now.  
<br/>
So I'm trying to make a discord verify bot. The only way you can verify is by verifying using the website that I'm currently working on with Django. And in the `bot python file` is where there is a say command to notify the user or something. But when I attempt on trying to import that python file, the server wouldn't run.  
<br/>
So I'm kinda stuck with the roadblock.

Comment: Does setting `urls.py` files work? If not, what happens when you go to your 'process' endpoint? (It should be something like http://localhost:8000/your-app/process)

Comment: Yep. Works, actually I'm sorry but I forgot to mention, I don't know if this would be helpful information, but I'll point it out anyway. So after you filled out the form and clicked submit, it would take you to the `process` thing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried below?

settings.py

```
import os, sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/Dir/") #Dir contains 'bot'
```

views.py

```
from Dic import bot
```

Basically, make your django project recognize the 'bot' path.